# Create lightbox on Kirby CMS for blog post

Tags: lightbox, kirby

I have a [blog](http://philgr.com) settled up on [Kirby CMS](http://getkirby.com). I have images attached on blog posts, the style for img contains max-width: 100%, every image has a URL to itself... I'd like to open these links as a lightbox instead of a page. Problem is that I can't use PHP for these cases since it is not a static page, all I have is CSS, HTML and Java, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) utilizes CSS and JavaScript to display the image in a modal window. You only need to load Lightbox JavaScript and CSS files with jQuery in the template and just add the attribute `rel="lightbox"` to your images to make it work.

Why isn't that working for you?